# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "org": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I am trying to create table using `anko` library in `kotlin` like below

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    db!!.createTable(PersonTable.Name, true,
            Pair(PersonTable.ID, INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT),
            Pair(PersonTable.PersonName, TEXT),
            Pair(PersonTable.Domain, TEXT),
            Pair(PersonTable.MobileNumber, REAL))
}
```

I am getting below error when I am adding `AUTOINCREMENT` to ID. It works without `AUTOINCREMENT`. What is the way to make any attribute as `AUTOINCREMENT` using `anko` library.

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.williamsro.fourthdemo, PID: 4799
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.williamsro.fourthdemo/com.williamsro.fourthdemo.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "org": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person`(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY org.jetbrains.anko.db.SqlTypeModifierImpl@7d0b905, person_name TEXT, domain TEXT, mobile_number REAL);
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "org": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person`(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY org.jetbrains.anko.db.SqlTypeModifierImpl@7d0b905, person_name TEXT, domain TEXT, mobile_number REAL);
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
      at org.jetbrains.anko.db.DatabaseKt.createTable(Database.kt:80)
      at com.williamsro.fourthdemo.AppDbHelpler.onCreate(AppDbHelpler.kt:17)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
      at org.jetbrains.anko.db.ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper.openDatabase(Database.kt:166)
      at org.jetbrains.anko.db.ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper.use(Database.kt:157)
      at com.williamsro.fourthdemo.MainActivity.insertPerson(MainActivity.kt:44)
      at com.williamsro.fourthdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:72)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: add string PersonTable.ID ="you name and all ";etc all here

Comment: @parikdhakan what do you mean?

Comment: If you see my code, there is nothing like that. I believe `AUTOINCREMENT` is being replaced by `org.jetbrains.anko.db.SqlTypeModifierImpl@7d0b905`

Comment: remove `AUTOINCREMENT` it is not necessary.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel It is necessary that's why I added. It works without it Is this bug in their library ?

Comment: yes we guess, you can check removing `AUTOINCREMENT` it is by default autoincr in primary key. I am using in my project.

Comment: add you table original field name here that you add. 
PersonTable.PersonName,PersonTable.Domain,
PersonTable.MobileNumber.

Comment: In my case, the error disappears doing the following: 1. remove AUTOINCREMENT; 2. Run the app; 3. restore AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: @mnishiguchi you are correct, try to make any attribute as AUTOINCREMENT then you will get same error that is bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an outdated version of Anko. With version *0.10* an issue with concatenating modifiers was fixed and reverted with version *0.10.1* again.

Before the relevant part of the code was `"$modifier $m"` where `$m` is the string representation of the modifier. Since it doesn't define a `toString()` method, the Java representation of the instance is used.

With the fix the code is `"$modifiers ${m.modifier}"`. Here `${m.modifier}` is actually a string.

If the latest fixes are not relevant for you, just use version *0.10*.

Comment: I am using `compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:0.10.1"` I think this is only the latest version they have right now

Comment: Ohh, for some reason this code is wrong with this release again. With _master_ it's fine though.

Comment: You know If I make one attribute AUTOINCREMENT then it throws this error https://pastebin.com/S7q1M9rc this is also a bug

Comment: I mean that I am trying to set property on one attribute in my table as AUTOINCREMENT then it throws this error https://pastebin.com/S7q1M9rc it should work. PS I am not applying AUTOINCREMENT on PRIMARY_KEY now

Comment: Did you read the documentation? _AUTOINCREMENT is not allowed on WITHOUT ROWID tables or on any table column other than INTEGER PRIMARY KEY._

Comment: Ah I see. How about PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT ? It should work right ?

Comment: It works with `master` and version `0.10`. Version `0.10.1` has the issue your stacktrace is pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and found a workaround. I was able to hardcode that part of SQL statement, using `SqlType.create` function.

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.createTable(CrimeTable.TABLE_NAME, true,
            CrimeTable.ID to SqlType.create("INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"),
            CrimeTable.UUID to TEXT,
            CrimeTable.TITLE to TEXT,
            CrimeTable.DATE to INTEGER,
            CrimeTable.IS_SOLVED to TEXT
    )
}
```

I checked the generated SQL in the DB Browser and it was working perfectly. I never got that error again ever since.

```
CREATE TABLE `crimes`(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, uuid TEXT, title TEXT, date INTEGER, isSolved TEXT)
```